# Two independent measures based on two time hierarchies

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap

I've got a simple cube with a fact table which has a date field among others and connected it with a time dimension which has 2 hierarchies.

What I want to do is create one measure that will be filtered only by the one time hierarchy and a second one for the second time hierarchy.

Basically this:

```
Measure1 ----> Cannot be affected by filtering of time_hierarchy2 and gets filtered only by time_hierarchy1
```

And the same for Measure2.

With what I've tried so far I can't do this because whenever I add a time hierarchy in the cube browser filter area, it affects both measures while I want them to be independent.
Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

In the way you have described your current data model this is not possible. Within Analysis Services if you were to review the **Dimension Usage** tab you will notice the dimension to measure group usage. For a single measure to dimension relationship the measure will be affected by all attributes/hierarchies of the related dimension when browsing the cube.

If a viable option would be to have a separate TimeKey in your fact you may establish a **Role Playing Dimension** and have multiple constraints from the your fact to Time dimension.

Another option could be similar to where I recently split this setup into multiple facts each with a single reference to the Time dimension so that I could the plot separate measures to the same graph on the same time axis. [How to avoid Role Playing Dimension](http://visual-intelligence.nu/how-to-avoid-role-playing-dimensions-in-ssas/)

Answer (score 1):

The idea is to create two instances (i.e [Cube Dimensions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ms174900.aspx)) of your [Database Dimension](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ms365412.aspx) and put one Hierarchy in each of them. This concept is also known as a [Role-Playing Dimension](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174487(v=sql.90).aspx).

You can then add filters using these role-playing dimensions to filter your Measures.