# select data from olap MDX query

Tags: ssas, mdx, olap, olap-cube

Please help to understand how MDX query works.
I have connected to cube using excel and construct a mdx query. In short finally I need to get the table like this:

```
                        12.01.2015
        +-------+-------+-------+-----+-------+------               
        | 00:00 | 01:00 | 02:00 | ... | 23:00 | TOTAL   
--------+-------+-------+-------+-----+-------+------
Ivan    | null  |   3   |  null | ... |   12  |  38
Pert    |   3   |   8   |  null | ... |  null | 125
Sidor   |
```

We see the `Date`, `Time` (hour), FIO (Ivan, Petr etc) and values.
The cube has dimensions: `Dim Date`, `Dim Hour`, `Dim Users`
I trying to get MDX query from excel but I cant understand how to modify it to get result I need. Here is the request (formatted):

```
SELECT NON EMPTY 
CrossJoin(
    Hierarchize(
        DrilldownMember(
        {
            {
                DrilldownMember(
                    {
                        {
                            DrilldownLevel
                                (
                                    {[Dim Date].[Даты YMD].[All]}
                                )
                        }
                    }, 
                    {[Dim Date].[Даты YMD].[Year Name].&[2015]}
                )
            }
        }, 
        {[Dim Date].[Даты YMD].[Year Name].&[2015].&[5]}
    )
), 
Hierarchize(
    {
        DrilldownLevel(
            {[Dim Hour].[Hour Key].[All]}
        )
    }
)) 
DIMENSION PROPERTIES PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME,
    [Dim Date].[Даты YMD].[Date Key].[Month Name],[Dim Date].[Даты YMD].[Date Key].[Year Name] ON COLUMNS , 
    NON EMPTY 
    Hierarchize(
        {
            DrilldownLevel(
                {[Dim Users].[FIO].[All]}
            )
        }
    ) 
DIMENSION PROPERTIES PARENT_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS  FROM 
(
    SELECT ({[Dim Date].[Даты YMD].[Year Name].&[2015].&[5]}
) 
    ON COLUMNS 
    FROM [Dwh Sorting]) 
    WHERE ([Measures].[Fact Table Count]) CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, 
    FORMAT_STRING, 
    LANGUAGE, 
    BACK_COLOR, 
    FORE_COLOR, 
    FONT_FLAGS
```

It gets data for May 2015. My goal is to get a long table (with a lot of columns) like I showed. With one or more months.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: He isn't getting any error. He wants data in a different format.

Comment: @user2598575 - Say you have three months. How does the data need to look like then?

Comment: @Sourav_Agasti do you know anything about cube design? I don't. Just some basic knowledge could answer this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30324119/two-independent-measures-based-on-two-time-hierarchies/30331786#30331786

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel code that is autogenerated adds a lot of extra "bits".

Getting rid of the extra bits I'm guessing at something like the below. This script should give you lots of columns - assuming data for every hour in 2015 you should end up with 24 columns for every day in 2015!

The reason I say "guessing" as we do not know the hiearchical structure of your cube:

```
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
      Descendants
      (
        [Dim Date].[Даты YMD].[Year Name].&[2015]
       ,[Dim Date].[Даты YMD].[Date] //<<this assumes there is a level in Dim date called Date
      )
    * 
      {[Dim Hour].[Hour Key].MEMBERS} ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    [Dim Users].[FIO].MEMBERS ON ROWS
FROM [Dwh Sorting]
WHERE 
  [Measures].[Fact Table Count];
```

If you need just the hours for a range of dates then try the `:` operator. You will not need to apply the `Descendants` function in this case:

```
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
      (
        [Dim Date].[Даты YMD].[Date Key].[2014-01-02]
      : 
        [Dim Date].[Даты YMD].[Date Key].[2015-02-10]
      )
    * 
      {[Dim Hour].[Hour Key].MEMBERS} ON COLUMNS
 ,NON EMPTY 
    [Dim Users].[FIO].MEMBERS ON ROWS
FROM [Dwh Sorting]
WHERE 
  [Measures].[Fact Table Count];
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. It returns a table where we have 25 columns. One column per hour and it sums all values matched hour from selected year. So If we have 12 months it aggregate values for every day. The structure of `Dim Date` is `Year Name`, `Month Name` and `Date Key`. So I have changed `[Date]` to `[Date Key]` and get needed result!

Comment: Against a simple question. How can I use `where` like in sql? For example I need to get only `2015.01.10' or range from '2015.01.10' to '2015.02.10'

Comment: I have modify line 5 to: `[Dim Date].[Даты YMD].[Date Key].[2014-01-02]` so in result I get only '2014-01-02' perfect! So the question is how to get range of dates?

Comment: @user2598575 you can get a range of dates using the operator `:`. MSDN article is here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146001.aspx